# Batch script output logging into file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to do logging of the below script for each command whether it is success or failure. I believe in shell script we have command `$?` to know whether the command executed is success or failure. Is there any way to achieve that in batch script?

```
open server
username
Password-1
bin
cd \Current_QA_DataLoad
put E:\AccountsInitialV6.txt
PAUSE
bye
```

Thanks in advance
Vikram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
yourCommand && (
   commands to execute upon success
) || (
   commands to execute upon failure
)
```